# Can not install wine on debian amd64:

Tags: debian, 64bit, wine

Can not install wine on debian amd64:

> sudo aptitude install wine-bin Note: selecting "wine-bin:i386" instead
>   of the
>         virtual package "wine-bin" The following NEW packages will be installed:   gcc-4.8-base:i386{ab} libasound2:i386{a} libc6:i386{a}
>   libc6-i686:i386{a}    libdbus-1-3:i386{a} libdrm-intel1:i386{a}
>   libdrm-nouveau2:i386{a}    libdrm-radeon1:i386{a} libdrm2:i386{a}
>   libexpat1:i386{a} libffi6:i386{a}    libfontconfig1:i386{a}
>   libfreetype6:i386{a} libgcc1:i386{ab}    libgcrypt11:i386{a}
>   libgl1-mesa-dri:i386{a} libgl1-mesa-glx:i386{a}
>   libglapi-mesa:i386{a} libglu1-mesa:i386{a} libgnutls26:i386{a}
>   libgpg-error0:i386{a} libgpm2:i386{a} libgsm1:i386{a} libice6:i386{a} 
>   libjbig0:i386 libjpeg8:i386{a} libllvm3.2:i386{a} libltdl7:i386{a}
>   liblzma5:i386{a} libmpg123-0:i386{a} libncurses5:i386{a}
>   libodbc1:i386{a}    libp11-kit0:i386{a} libpciaccess0:i386{a}
>   libpng12-0:i386{a}    libsm6:i386{a} libssl1.0.0:i386{a}
>   libstdc++6:i386{ab} libtasn1-3:i386{a}    libtiff4:i386{a}
>   libtinfo5:i386{a} libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386{a}    libuuid1:i386{a}
>   libv4l-0:i386{a} libv4lconvert0:i386{a} libwine:i386{a}
>   libwine-alsa:i386{a} libwine-bin:i386{a} libwine-gecko-1.4{a}
>   libwine-gl:i386{a} libx11-6:i386{a} libx11-xcb1:i386{a}
>   libxau6:i386{a}    libxcb-dri2-0:i386{a} libxcb-glx0:i386{a}
>   libxcb1:i386{a}    libxcomposite1:i386{a} libxcursor1:i386{a}
>   libxdamage1:i386{a}    libxdmcp6:i386{a} libxext6:i386{a}
>   libxfixes3:i386{a} libxi6:i386{a}    libxinerama1:i386{a}
>   libxml2:i386{a} libxrandr2:i386{a}    libxrender1:i386{a}
>   libxslt1.1:i386{a} libxxf86vm1:i386{a}    wine-bin:i386{b}
>   zlib1g:i386{a}  0 packages upgraded, 71 newly installed, 0 to remove
>   and 0 not upgraded. Need to get 84.1 MB of archives. After unpacking
>   253 MB will be used. The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
>   gcc-4.8-base : Breaks: gcc-4.8-base:i386 (!= 4.8.1-7) but 4.8.1-6 is
>   to be installed.  gcc-4.8-base:i386 : Breaks: gcc-4.8-base (!=
>   4.8.1-6) but 4.8.1-7 is installed.  libgcc1 : Breaks: libgcc1:i386 (!= 1:4.8.1-7) but 1:4.8.1-6 is to be installed.  libgcc1:i386 : Breaks:
>   libgcc1 (!= 1:4.8.1-6) but 1:4.8.1-7 is installed.  libstdc++6 :
>   Breaks: libstdc++6:i386 (!= 4.8.1-7) but 4.8.1-6 is to be installed. 
>   libstdc++6:i386 : Breaks: libstdc++6 (!= 4.8.1-6) but 4.8.1-7 is
>   installed.  wine-bin:i386 : Conflicts: wine64-bin but 1.5.30-2 is
>   installed. The following actions will resolve these dependencies:
>
> ```
>   Keep the following packages at their current version:           1)      gcc-4.8-base:i386 [Not Installed]
> ```
>
> 2)      libasound2:i386 [Not Installed]
>   3)      libc6:i386 [Not Installed]
>   4)      libc6-i686:i386 [Not Installed]
>   5)      libdbus-1-3:i386 [Not Installed]
>   6)      libdrm-intel1:i386 [Not Installed]
>   7)      libdrm-nouveau2:i386 [Not Installed]
>   8)      libdrm-radeon1:i386 [Not Installed]
>   9)      libdrm2:i386 [Not Installed]
>   10)     libexpat1:i386 [Not Installed]
>   11)     libffi6:i386 [Not Installed]
>   12)     libfontconfig1:i386 [Not Installed]
>   13)     libfreetype6:i386 [Not Installed]
>   14)     libgcc1:i386 [Not Installed]
>   15)     libgcrypt11:i386 [Not Installed]
>   16)     libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 [Not Installed]
>   17)     libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 [Not Installed]
>   18)     libglapi-mesa:i386 [Not Installed]
>   19)     libglu1-mesa:i386 [Not Installed]
>   20)     libgnutls26:i386 [Not Installed]
>   21)     libgpg-error0:i386 [Not Installed]
>   22)     libgpm2:i386 [Not Installed]
>   23)     libgsm1:i386 [Not Installed]
>   24)     libice6:i386 [Not Installed]
>   25)     libjbig0:i386 [Not Installed]
>   26)     libjpeg8:i386 [Not Installed]
>   27)     libllvm3.2:i386 [Not Installed]
>   28)     libltdl7:i386 [Not Installed]
>   29)     liblzma5:i386 [Not Installed]
>   30)     libmpg123-0:i386 [Not Installed]
>   31)     libncurses5:i386 [Not Installed]
>   32)     libodbc1:i386 [Not Installed]
>   33)     libp11-kit0:i386 [Not Installed]
>   34)     libpciaccess0:i386 [Not Installed]
>   35)     libpng12-0:i386 [Not Installed]
>   36)     libsm6:i386 [Not Installed]
>   37)     libssl1.0.0:i386 [Not Installed]
>   38)     libstdc++6:i386 [Not Installed]
>   39)     libtasn1-3:i386 [Not Installed]
>   40)     libtiff4:i386 [Not Installed]
>   41)     libtinfo5:i386 [Not Installed]
>   42)     libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 [Not Installed]
>   43)     libuuid1:i386 [Not Installed]
>   44)     libv4l-0:i386 [Not Installed]
>   45)     libv4lconvert0:i386 [Not Installed]
>   46)     libwine:i386 [Not Installed]
>   47)     libwine-alsa:i386 [Not Installed]
>   48)     libwine-bin:i386 [Not Installed]
>   49)     libwine-gl:i386 [Not Installed]
>   50)     libx11-6:i386 [Not Installed]
>   51)     libx11-xcb1:i386 [Not Installed]
>   52)     libxau6:i386 [Not Installed]
>   53)     libxcb-dri2-0:i386 [Not Installed]
>   54)     libxcb-glx0:i386 [Not Installed]
>   55)     libxcb1:i386 [Not Installed]
>   56)     libxcomposite1:i386 [Not Installed]
>   57)     libxcursor1:i386 [Not Installed]
>   58)     libxdamage1:i386 [Not Installed]
>   59)     libxdmcp6:i386 [Not Installed]
>   60)     libxext6:i386 [Not Installed]
>   61)     libxfixes3:i386 [Not Installed]
>   62)     libxi6:i386 [Not Installed]
>   63)     libxinerama1:i386 [Not Installed]
>   64)     libxml2:i386 [Not Installed]
>   65)     libxrandr2:i386 [Not Installed]
>   66)     libxrender1:i386 [Not Installed]
>   67)     libxslt1.1:i386 [Not Installed]
>   68)     libxxf86vm1:i386 [Not Installed]
>   69)     wine-bin:i386 [Not Installed]
>   70)     zlib1g:i386 [Not Installed]
>
> ```
>   Leave the following dependencies unresolved:                    71)     libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 recommends libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 7.2)
> ```
>
> 72)     libncurses5:i386 recommends libgpm2:i386
>   73)     libwine:i386 recommends libgsm1:i386 (>= 1.0.13)
>   74)     libwine:i386 recommends libv4l-0:i386 (>= 0.5.0)

Comment: What does `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` say?

Comment: dpkg --print-foreign-architectures show: i386

Comment: Try to remove `wine64-bin` first.

Comment: It did not help me

Comment: So what is the new error message?